# Multi- threading in Java - trouble with implmenting in program

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I created the below bouncing ball program. I'm new to programming in general, but got this working fine. The objective was to have the ball bounce within the frame and to appear in random locations at program start up.

the next thing I am trying to do is to intoduce multiple balls into the frame that bounce around. I'm trying to do this using the Rnnable interface but havent been able to get this working. The Balls can move independently, passing through each other. Each Ball should have its own thread, rather than one thread updating an array of Balls.Below is my attempt but I havent able to get this working.

Any advice would be great.

```
/*Bounce class*/

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Bounce2 extends JPanel implements Runnable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  /*variables*/
  int x, y;
  int anglex = 1, angley = 1, speed = 10;
  int min = 40, max = 760;

  public Bounce2() {
    min = 60;
    max = 740;
  }

  public void setGenerateRandom (int max, int min) {
    x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max +1);
    y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max +1);
    run();
  }

  public void run() {
    if (x + anglex < 0) {
      anglex = speed;
    } else if (x + anglex > getWidth() - 50) {
      anglex = -speed;
    } else if (y + angley < 0) {
      angley = speed;
    } else if (y + angley > getHeight() - 50) {
      angley = -speed;
    }

    x = x + anglex;
    y = y + angley;
  }

  public void paint (Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); 
    Color c = Color.blue;
    g.setColor(c);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 80, 80);   
  }

  public void random() {
    setGenerateRandom(max, min);
  }

}
```

```
/*Bounce2Test class*/
    
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Bounce2Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    {
      int num = 0;
      String objects;

      objects = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter number of balls!");
      num = Integer.parseInt(objects);

      // Number of threads
      for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        Thread object = new Thread(new Bounce2());
        object.start();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bouncing Ball");
        Bounce2 ball = new Bounce2();
        frame.add(ball);
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ball.random();

        while(true) {
          ball.run();
          ball.repaint();
          Thread.sleep(10);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Watch your spelling of key terms. Misspellings decrease the chance of search hits.

Comment: Things that caught my attention: you have an unnecessary "top level" block inside your `main` method, you create a `JFrame` (top-level-container) within a `JFrame` - (because you add the `Bounce2` instance to the outer `JFrame`) - did you do this on purpose?

Comment: Re, "Each Ball should have its own thread" Why? Is this a homework assignment? In general it is _not_ a good idea to have one thread for every moving object in a game/simulation/eye-candy animation/etc. It's more efficient to have a single thread that's responsible for the timing. (At least, anyway, one thread responsible for all of the "dumb" moving objects. If it's a game and if you have some "intelligent monsters," then it could make sense for each one to have its own thread that implements its own special strategy.)